# MongoDB query objects which coordinates fit in a certain range

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a document that stores number of locations. My Goal is to find all locations that are between certain latitude and longitute. My approachh for now is not very efficent. I get all of the locations and filter them in a for cycle. I want to use the $range method.

```
locationsCollection.find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
    var locations = [];
    for(var key in results){
        if( 
            results[key].latitude > req.query.latitude - latitudeOffset &&
            results[key].latitude < req.query.latitude + latitudeOffset && 
            results[key].longitude > req.query.longitude - longitudeOffset && 
            results[key].longitude < req.query.longitude + longitudeOffset
            )
            locations.push({
                location: results[key].location,
                latitude: results[key].latitude,
                longitude: results[key].longitude
            });
    }

    res.json({error: false, locations: locations});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do so using MongoDB's [geospatial query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/).

MongoDB allows you to work using [GeoJSON objects](http://geojson.org/), which is a standard for describing location data using JSON.

For example, I have a collection of locations:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id": 0, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 1 ] } }
{ "_id": 1, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 2 ] } }
{ "_id": 2, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 20, 20 ] } }
```

with the special [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/):

```
> db.test.createIndex({loc: '2dsphere'})
```

Then I want to find which locations are within a specific "box", described using [GeoJSON's polygon object](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6):

```
> db.test.find({
    loc: {
        $geoWithin: {
            $geometry: {
                type: 'Polygon',
                coordinates: [ [ [0,0], [3,6], [6,1], [0,0] ] ]
            }
        }
    }
})
```

result is:

```
{ "_id": 0, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 1, 1 ] } }
{ "_id": 1, "loc": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 2, 2 ] } }
```

where it shows that the location with the coordinates of `[20, 20]` is located outside the bounding box in the query.

**Note**: MongoDB's geospatial query follows the earth's curvature as per [geodesy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy). That is, the curvature of the earth is taken into account when the query using a `2dsphere` index is processed. Most map is a sphere projected into a flat 2d plane, so what looks like a straight line in 2d, will not be a straight line in a sphere.

**Note**: GeoJSON's coordinate system order is `[ Longitude, Latitude ]`, which is reversed from the typical (Latitude, Longitude) pair.

Comment: This is a great explanation! However I was looking for a general solution to the problem and find a way to query objects where value is in certain range, as I might end up using it for other use cases.